# Excel 2010 - Data From Web creating a new file?

Tags: excel, rest, jira, excel-2010

I am trying to set up a sheet in my excel Workbook where the data is from the web. That way I can click refresh and the data will be pulled from the site again, basically automating what is currently a new process.

Right now we are exporting the data from a site into an excel file and then copy/pasting it into the second workbook and generating our reports there, I want to avoid doing this, clicking refresh should refresh the data.

The data I am trying to pull is from the OnDemand JIRA application we are using to track our agile team process. (URL https://mycompany.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/10101/SearchRequest-10101.xls?tempMax=1000)

Now the problem is that if I select Data -> From Web in Excel 2010 and I enter the above URL, Excel always wants to save the data into another Excel file....is there any way I can have it insert the data in the workbook I already have open (the one I clicked Data -> From Web in?)? I can't seem to find any way to do this right now so any help is appreciated!

I don't know too much about REST but is there a better way to do this other than using Data -> From Web? Keep in mind I want to avoid the copy/paste of the data from one spreadsheet to another and the data will be refreshed weekly. Thank YOU!

Comment: I'm guessing that URL returns an Excel file and not HTML, so you may not be able to use a web query.  In VBA you can likely just do `Workbooks.Open(yourURLHere)`, then copy and paste from that file into your existing workbook.

Comment: Unless you want to parse out the XML you're stuck with copy/paste, but I don't see why that's such an issue - can easily be automated.

Comment: Well for me its not a big issue, but others seem to think so :( haha. How can it be automated?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started...

```
Sub DoUpdate()

Const URL As String = "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:" & _
                       "searchrequest-excel-all-fields/10101/" & _
                       "SearchRequest-10101.xls?tempMax=1000)"

Dim wb As Workbook


    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(URL) 'open workbook from web

    'clear previous data
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A1:H200").ClearContents

    'copy new data over
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
                      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A1")


    wb.Close False 'close and don't save any changes

End Sub
```